# How to get just my apps logs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've got my website built on node.js with express.js, and I use morgan as a logger. I'm on Elastic Beanstalk, and I'm trying to tail into my logs. Wow, there's a lot of stuff in there. I can't make heads or tails of all this. Is there a way to just get my app's logs?

Comment: Are you using load balancer?

Comment: So just enable the ELB Loggin and you can access the logs for you App in the S3 bucket.

Comment: I'm tailing into the logs from my console. I can see the logs just fine, I'm just looking to pair down to just the logs my app prints, rather than all the nginx and other logs that are in there.

Comment: Did you check this article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-logging-and-log-rotation-in-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-vps